# mysqli_fetch_array sem usar while

Tags: php

Bom faço uma consulta no Mysql assim:

```
$usuario = $conexao->query("select * from cadastros");
```

Monto um json assim:

```
// Monta array das tabelas
while ($resultado_tabelas = mysqli_fetch_object($usuario)) {

    // Monta array
    $tabelas[] = array(
        "id" => (int) $resultado_tabelas->id,
        "nome" => $resultado_tabelas->nome
    );
}
```

Tem como fazer isso sem usar o `while`? Eu tentei assim:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($usuario, MYSQLI_ASSOC),
```

Porém só obtenho 1 resultado.

Answer (score 3):

Se tiver o [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.plugin.php) instalado pode usar a função [mysqli_fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) ela é equivalmente ao `fetchAll()` do PDO ou seja retorna todos os resultados/linhas da consulta de uma vez só.

```
$result = $conexao->query("select * from cadastros");
echo json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sem o while tem como, sem loop não tem como, a não ser que faça um por um, o que não faz sentido, use o foreach.

```
 <?php
    $arr = mysqli_fetch_array($usuario, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    foreach($arr as $row){

    }
```